# To convert a hex value to a hex string in Perl

Tags: perl

Consider:

```
$index = 0;

$start_addr = 0x50000000;

for (i=$index; $i<256; $i++)
{
    $addr = sprintf("%X",($start_addr = $start_addr + 4));

    print "addr:$addr\n";
}
```

I get the numbers in their hex form (as 50000000, 50000004, 50000008, 5000000C and so on..). My requirement is that I should get it as 0x50000000,0x50000004 and so on... For that I thought of converting this to a hex string ("5000000C") and concatenating 0x(with . operator like 0x.5000000C) to that and again converting back to hex value (0x5000000C). But I am not getting how to start with. Does there exist a better solution to this?

Comment: Assorted nitpicks:  
(1) `use strict; use warnings;` especially when you are new to Perl.
(2) Variable `$i` isn't really used.  
(3) You forgot the sigil `$` on the first occurence of `$i`.  
(4) The for-loop can be written elegantly with a *range*: `for my $i ($index .. 256-1){...}`. You can omit the `my $i` as the variable has no use.  
(5) `$a = $a op $b` where `op` is an operator is the same as `$a op= $b`, here: `$start_addr += 4`.  
(6) Why not use `printf`? `printf "addr:0x%x\n", ($start_addr += 4)`.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `0x` to the `sprintf` pattern:

```
sprintf("0x%X",($start_addr = $start_addr + 4));
```